# Get value from ini file and modify the value in shell script

Tags: shell

I am creating shell script that get values from an `.ini` file and modify that value.

In ini file, value is saved as following structure:

```
key1 = value1
```

I get value1 in shell as

```
SHELL_VALUE = ${key1}
```

It is still ok and I get `value1` in `SHELL_VALUE` .

But, I concatenate `SHELL_VALUE` with a value `ab` with following syntax

```
FINAL_VALUE = ${SHELL_VALUE}"ab".
```

I want the result as `value1ab` but right now I get `ablue1` instead and the first two char `va` are overridden by `ab`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 `FINAL_VALUE = "${SHELL_VALUE}ab"`
```

instead of

```
  `FINAL_VALUE = ${SHELL_VALUE}"ab"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Note also crudini which should be available on your distro. You can use that to get the value from the ini file in a more robust way